# refresh the page with ajax on a social network website

Tags: ajax, yii

I want to create a social network website. but there is a problem when the page refreshes the page with ajax. there I am using setInterval every 5 seconds. but by the time the page refreshes, textarea also comments on reloading. how to order textarea in the comments do not reload when the page refreshes? 
please help me !

Comment: Stop interval when your textarea get focus and restart interval on blur. Best idea : do not reload your textarea, reload only useful data (stats, new activity if changed...)

Answer (score 0):

Can You put up your Code in order to understand your problem more Precisely.?

Use :

$.ajax({

```
                url: '--URL of ajax Page--',

                type: 'POST',

                data: {},

                success: function(data) {

                    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {

                        **window.location.reload();**     // This reloads the Page in a faster way.

                    });


                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

my code like this: 
The page refreshes (_view.php)

```
<div class="status">
<?php echo '&nbsp;<span style="color: #f83e07">#SIF# '.$data->idUser->short_name.'</span> : '.date("D, d M Y, H:m:s",strtotime($data->tgl_update)).'</br>'.CHtml::link(CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/member/'.$data->idUser->foto,'',array("width"=>50,"height"=>50)), array('user/view', 'id'=>$data->id_user)).'</br>';
            if($data->id_user == Yii::app()->user->id){ 
            }
            echo '</br><div class="isi">'.strip_tags($data->isi, "<h1><u><div><br><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><img><hr><font><b>").'</div>'; ?>``
```

reload the index page (index.php)

```
function callAjax(){
$.fn.yiiListView.update('datalist', {
               data: $(this).serialize(),
               success: function(html){
                    $('.view').mouseout(function(e){
                        ref = setInterval(function(){callAjax();}, 5000);
                        });
                    $('.view').click(function(e){
                        clearInterval(ref);
                    });

            },
          }
      );
}
```